# Swift extension files: ViewContoller goes into extension file function without call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can someone help me understand why this bug is occurring.

When I perform a segue to a certain view controller the program calls a function that is in an extension file even though the view controller file does not have any call to said function.

I have print statements in each file so i can see the program is going into ViewControllerUniversity.swift and then into loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String).

Below are the two files I'm having issues with:

```
//
//  ViewControllerUniversity.swift
//  
//


import UIKit

class ViewControllerUniversity: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


//var to hold university
var userUniversity = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Gone into SELECT UNIVERSITY")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/****
* CONTINUE
* continue with sign up
****/

@IBOutlet var selectUniversityWarningLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func contButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if userUniversity != ""
    {
        if userUniversity != "-"
        {
            //set user university
            thisUser.setUniversity(uni: userUniversity)


            //go to signup
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromSignIn1ToSignIn2", sender: self)

        } else
        {
            print("Select university")
            selectUniversityWarningLabel.text = "Please select a university from list above. "
        }
    }else
    {
        print("Select university")
        selectUniversityWarningLabel.text = "Please select a university from list above."
    }

}



@IBOutlet var universityPickerView: UIPickerView!

/****
 * PICKER VIEW
 * Shows the universites available
 ****/


@IBOutlet var uniPickerView: UIPickerView!


let universityList = ["-", "University"]

//number of rows
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return universityList[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return universityList.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    userUniversity = universityList[row]
}

}
```

Extension file

```
//
//  extensions.swift
//  


import UIKit

//stores images
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {


func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String){
    print("Gone into LOADIMAGEUSINGCACHE")
    self.image = nil

    //check cache for image
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject){
        self.image = cachedImage as! UIImage
        return
    }

    //otherwise download the image
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        //update user profile pciture to cell
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!){
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                self.image = downloadedImage
            }


        }



    }).resume()
}

}
```

Comment: The view life cycle and application life cycle will be called automatically not the custom functions. Check everywhere whether you called that particular function.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString`, then look in the trace where it was called from.

Comment: I've looked at the code and ran with breakpoints. It appears that once the viewdidload() function is complete the program goes directly into the extensions.swift file. I don't understand this at all.

Comment: side note, ViewControllerUniversity is not a good name. Try UniversityViewController instead. its more idiomatic.

Comment: Side note 2, putting the download code in an extension for the image is not very flexible when you also need to download other data types. Check out this link for a possible improved approach: http://matteomanferdini.com/network-requests-rest-apis-ios-swift/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for advice.

Upon inspecting the received actions on the view controller that loads before ViewControllerUniversity, I found that I had connected two submit buttons together. I think pressing submit on one view controller would load ViewControllerUniversity and then immediately call the button.